# Remove body from PUT request in ngResource query

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, rest, ngresource

I'm should to send a **PUT** query for some url. 
But rest **reject** my query if it contains any body(JSON, like {"id": 1}).
When I'm use ngResource instead of $http, query already contains a body. How can I remove it?

Sample of expected url:

```
http://some.com/rest/some/1/smth?method=start
```

Url contains :id param and thats why my factory looks like this:

```
.factory('ApiResourceFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        return {
            payment: $resource('http://some.com/rest/some/:id/smth',
                {orderId: '@id'},
                {
                    start: {method: "PUT", 'params': {'method': "start"}},
                    //...
                }
            )
         }
}])
```

Thats how I use it:

```
var id = 1;
ApiResourceFactory.payment.start({id: id}, function () {
    //on success
}, function (responce) {
    //on error
});
```

**The problem is**: The "**id**" param sends not only in url, but in request body too (request payload) as {"id": 1}.

Without body (when I'm use $http, for example), query success, but wit  body server rejects my query.

So. **How can** I tell ngResource clear or **do not** fill the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular documentation of `$resource` is not very good, but if you look at the last example on the documentation you would get your answer. See section "Creating a custom 'PUT' request
"

The way you have setup `params` is not correct. If you use `@` then the parameter matching happens from body content. You do not need to provide `params` object. Also the call to start method is also slightly different.

See my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/wLQnq/